# Table size increasing in Latex

Tags: latex, multiple-columns, tabular, overleaf

How Can I increase the entire size of this table to take large height and width in latex
there is the code

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Recognition rate $\pm$ Standad deviation $\%$ of RFME and SGRFME over 20 splits of experiments}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{A} & B & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{F}      &   &            &           &            &           &            &           \\ \cline{2-8} 
                        &   &            &           &            &           &            &           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] with all the packages etc necessary to compile your code fragment?